# scipy's shgo optimizer fails to minimize variance

Tags: optimization, scipy, shgo

In order to get familiar with global optimization methods and in particular with the `shgo` optimizer from `scipy.optimize v1.3.0` I have tried to minimize the variance `var(x)` of a vector `x = [x1,...,xN]` with `0 <= xi <= 1` under the constraint that `x` has a given average value:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import shgo

# Constraint
avg = 0.5  # Given average value of x
cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.mean(x)-avg}

# Minimize the variance of x under the given constraint
res = shgo(lambda x: np.var(x), bounds=6*[(0, 1)], constraints=cons)
```

The `shgo` method fails on this problem:

```py
>>> res
     fun: 0.0
 message: 'Failed to find a feasible minimiser point. Lowest sampling point = 0.0'
    nfev: 65
     nit: 2
   nlfev: 0
   nlhev: 0
   nljev: 0
 success: False
       x: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

The correct solution would be the uniform distribution `x = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]` and it can be easily found by using the local optimizer `minimize` from `scipy.optimize`:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numpy.random import random

x0 = random(6)  # Random start vector
res2 = minimize(lambda x: np.var(x), x0, bounds=6*[(0, 1)], constraints=cons)
```

The `minimize` method yields the correct result for arbitrary start vectors:

```py
>>> res2.success
True

>>> res2.x
array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```

My question is: Why `shgo` fails on this relatively simple task? Did I made a mistake or is `shgo` simply not usable for this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FWIW: `shgo` works if `bounds` is changed to `6*[(-0.1, 1)]`.  If you have a moment, you could report the issue on the SciPy github site: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues

Comment: Thank you very much Warren! It is true, by changing the bounds like you said, the `shgo` method works well. This makes the problem rather look like a bug. I will make the report on the SciPy site.