# How to use scipy.optimize.minimize within Keras model.compile?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scipy

I have a custom loss f = x + y where I have constraints such that while optimising f, x should be within a range of (0.10, 0.2) and y within the range of (0.6, 0.1), y is the mean square difference between the actual and predicted labels and x is different types of jobs. The model is not trained based on x; however, it's required to be optimized on getting different types of jobs within the prediction.

I came across [Scipy.optimize: how to restrict argument values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244527/scipy-optimize-how-to-restrict-argument-values) on how scipy.optimize can be used with bounds of the parameter of a function. However, my main problem is that I have a custom loss function total_loss(y_pred, y_true) and it works with Keras as a loss function using "SGD" as optimizer. Now, for incorporating the bound range of the parameter, I would like to use scipy.optimize.minimise with Keras. Any direction on how to use scipy.optimize on model.compile in Keras?

Comment: Please be more specific: What are `x` and `y`? Are they coefficients? How are they incorporated into loss function? As for: "I would like to use scipy.optimize.minimise with Keras" No, you can't do that. You need to use built-in optimizers of Keras or define a new optimizer based on (Keras/TF) tensor operations.

Comment: I have added more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom training loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough).
The training loop can collect the gradients considering your keras loss function and you can then choose to optimize the weights using a given constraint.

I've implemented something [similar](https://github.com/pedro-r-marques/keras-opt/blob/master/keras_opt/scipy_optimizer.py#L94); this code calls SciPy minimize to optimize a model's variables.